# How to use double to test exception handling in unit testing in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to test my send method logic in my Client class. I have this so far in my client_spec file. How can i raise and error and test that rescue is called and the error is logged in my spec file. 
I am new to rspec but I believe i can use a test double for logging instead of calling actual logger.

client_spec.rb

```
describe Client do

 describe '#send' do 
   let (:subject) {Client.new}

   it 'raises and logs the exception'
       //how to test raising and logging of the error
   end
 end
end
```

client.rb

```
class Client
  include HTTParty 
  base_uri "https://www.example.com"
  format :json

  def send
    begin 
      response = HTTParty.get(url)
      if response.successful?
        response 
      else
        raise 'invalid response'
      end
    rescue HTTParty::Error => e 
      logger.warn(e.message)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In `Client`, where does `logger` come from?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can stub both `HTTParty` and `logger`, something like

```
let(:logger) { double('Logger') } 
let(:error) { HTTParty::Error.new('foo') }   

 before do
   allow(Logger).to receive(:new) { logger }
 end
```

(Not sure what kind of logger are you using)

and then you can tell `HTTParty` to raise the kind of error you're expecting, like:

```
 context 'when there is a HTTParty error' do
   before do
     allow(HTTParty).to receive(:get).and_raise(error)
   end
   it 'logs the error' do
     expect(logger).to receive(:warn).with('foo')
     subject.send
   end
 end
```

Comment: thanks. I am using the inbuilt logger class. in your context block, I noticed expect statement is before subject.send. how does that work? also, i know with mock/stub we don't actually test our actual method code, but create mocks to mimic functionality. is the test , I have here covers unit testing of my method?

Comment: @arve `expect(thing).to receive(:method).and_raise(error)` sets up a mock `thing.method` which expects to be called once as `thing.method('foo')`. If it isn't called the test fails. It must be done before `subject.send` so the mocked method is in place. This tests that `Client#send` will send HTTParty errors to your logger as a warning, only a portion of `Client#send`'s functionality.

Comment: @thank you both for you help. when I run this, i actuallly get the error that, this line ->  allow(HTTParty).to receive(:get).and_raise(error) , throws an Excon exception and rspec fails. I also read that , while testing raising exceptions, the code should be in a expect block , somthing like this expect {some code}.to raise_error()

Comment: I'm getting an runtime error, of the error being thrown in the spec method. when i run the test

Comment: @mr_sudaca - let me know if you any thoughts on the exception, i'm getting. is there a alternative way to test the exception handling?

Comment: What’s the error you’re having? Mahal be it’s another exception. In the example, I’m just “stubbing” a HTTParty::Error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, the `expect` before the `send` is a way to test if the tested method will "trigger" or perform additional operations, it's a way to say "when I execute foo, I expect that "this" happened". There is a way to declare way around, like:

```
subject.send
expect(logger).to have_received(:warn).with('foo')
```

But I think this way is newer than the one I proposed, I just got really used to use the proposed one.

About mocks and stubs, yeah, you don't test them because those objects are out of the scope of the class you're testing on. So, `Logger` should have its own set of tests, the same for `HTTParty`, so, you "simulate" their behaviors in order to test your class, that way you'll remove the dependency between the test and other libraries (or classes). 
When your unit test is done, then you can move to an integration test, and test (sorry for the redundancy) that the whole stack (or endpoint or controller or "flow") is doing what you're expecting to do.